# How to deal with react router url params and type script

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

In react router, I am going through the tutorial but trying to use typescript and have this code

```
let params = useParams();
let id:string = params.invoiceId
let invoice = getInvoice(parseInt(id, 10));
```

The second line has an error

```
TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

How do I do this properly to lookup and display the invoice?  Also, how to reroute to the catch all * if the string is not an integer.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I do this properly to lookup and display the invoice?

The `invoiceId` route param is potentially undefined and typed as `"string | undefined"` so your `id` type should match.

```
const params = useParams();
const id: string | undefined = params.invoiceId;
```

Since `id` is now also potentially undefined, and the `parseInt` expects a string type you can either:

1. Use a guard-clause:

   ```
   const invoice = id && getInvoice(parseInt(id, 10));
   ```
2. Or use the `Number` constructor which takes an optional `any` type:

   ```
   const invoice = getInvoice(Number(id));
   ```

> Also, how to reroute to the catch all * if the string is not an
> integer.

If you want to check/test the `id` parameter first to ensure it is a integer you can use a regular expression to test for only number characters and issue an imperative redirect.

Example:

```
const navigate = useNavigate();

...

useEffect(() => {
  if (id && /[^\d]/g.test(id)) {
    navigate("/", { replace: true });
  }
}, [id, navigate]);
```

[image: Edit how-to-deal-with-react-router-url-params-and-type-script]